# Opencpu data caching

Tags: r, opencpu

My speciality is java. I use R for very specific analyses.

**PROBLEM**

1. My understanding is that each API call to opencpu opens a new R session.
2. My function will classify the data input using the predict method of a linear discriminant analysis (lda from MASS package).
3. The initial linear discriminant analysis on 100000+ cases and 150+ factor levels takes time (over 30 seconds). This function returns a list.
4. The subsequent prediction function is quick and returns a simple vector.

**APPROACH**

1. I run one opencpu function to run the initial lda. This only needs to run once.
2. I want my second function to ONLY run the predict function. This is possible if the lda is held as a global variable.
3. My understanding is that global variables are not possible in opencpu. So I will have to cache the lda on the file system.
4. In sum, I need to run the lda just once and hold the analysis (a list) either in memory or on the file system. I then retrieve the lda analysis when predict is called.

**QUESTION**

Which approach is best, and how to implement?

1. I could use an opencpu function that creates and returns the lda. Then when I call a prediction, I could retrieve the lda object (a list) from the file system. But how do I retrieve the list from the file system. How does opencpu even know where it is?
2. I could use r.cache package. I haven't used this package before but the docs suggest it is a solution. Will this work?

Any advice would be deeply appreciated.

best
jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package r.cache solves the problem very easily